# Help with an integral equation: $\int_0^h \sinh\left(\sqrt{p^2z^2 + ptz + t^2}\right)\ \text{d}z = D$

Tags: integration

I need some help with this integral:

$$\int_0^h \sinh\left(\sqrt{p^2z^2 + ptz + t^2}\right)\ \text{d}z = D$$

$t$ is unknown constant. $h$, $p$ and $D$ are known constants

I tried Taylor series expansion dropping higher order terms. But I was wondering if it is possible to solve this using some analytical treatment. After solving this integration I should be able to get a polynomial interms of $t$. Thereafter I have to solve for $t$.
Thanks

Fir simplicity the integrand may be written as

$$\int_0^h\sinh\sqrt{Ax^2 + Bx + C}\ \text{d}x$$

Comment: 'Help' means that you've tried something yourself. Can you please share it?

Comment: Hello, The function is highly non linear. I tries talor series expansion dropping higher order terms. But was wondering if there is any analytical treatment

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I think you misunderstood a key aspect of this site. This is more about *helping* you find the right answer then giving you answers to arbitrary problems. For example, if you were to give us what you've tried, where you've looked, what you've read to answer the problem, and describe why you aren't satisfied/doubt what you've come across, I'm sure others would help. Also, choosing a descriptive title that described the content would help. For more, I recommend reading [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9754)

Comment: What is $E$? I don't see any $E$ in the problem...

Comment: I apologize, it should be h instraed of E. Sorry for the glitches from my side.

Comment: (If $h$ is a constant too, then there is no equation to solve) Is $B^2-4AC<0$ ?

Comment: Actually, B, A and C constants are used for normalization and consists of some unknown constants. So it's hard to figure out if B^2-4AC<0

Comment: What happens if you differentiate both sides?

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. I am new to this forum and getting used to writing the equation using scripts. Please bear with my mistakes. Thanks

Comment: This equation itself was obtained after taking integral of a differential equation. so not sure if it is going to help. thanks

Comment: When you write "*equation*", you want to find at least one *unknown* in terms of at least one *constant* (or *parameter*). Which ones, among $A,B,C, D$ and $E:=h$ are the parameters and which ones are the unknowns?

Comment: A=p^2, B=p*TAU, C=TAU^2. After solving the integral equation I should be getting a polynomial in terms of TAU. Thereafter I have to come up with an equation TAU=(...)

Answer (score 1):

We shall analyse case by case. The simplest one is surely when you have

$$\Delta = B^2 - 4AC = 0 ~~~ \to ~~~ x = -\frac{B}{2A}$$

In that case:

$$\int_0^h\sinh\sqrt{\left(x + \frac{B}{2A}\right)^2}\ \text{d}x = \int_0^h\sinh\left(x + \frac{B}{2A}\right)\ \text{d}x = D$$

The integral is then trivial:

$$\int_0^h\sinh\left(x + \frac{B}{2A}\right)\ \text{d}x = \cosh\left(\frac{B}{2A} + h\right)-\cosh\left(\frac{B}{2A}\right)$$

Hence

$$D = \cosh\left(\frac{B}{2A} + h\right)-\cosh\left(\frac{B}{2A}\right)$$

**Second Case**

Things get really complicated when you have

$$\Delta = B^2 - 4AC > 0$$

Obtaining two solutions:

$$x_{1,\ 2} = \frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A} = (x_1, x_2)$$

In this case the integration becomes

$$\int_0^h \sinh\sqrt{(x + x_1)(x + x_2)}\ \text{d}x = D = $$

$$ = \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{1}{4} (x_1-x_2)^2} \left(e^{\frac{1}{2} (x_1-x_2)^2} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+h\right)\right)+\text{erfi}\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+h\right)-\text{erfi}\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)\right)$$

Which you can see is really not easy. You deal with special functions, and it all depends on $h$.

**Last Case**

In this case we have

$$\Delta = B^2 - 4AC < 0$$

I don't feel like I can write anything explicit or sure about. So I pass.

**Other possibilities**

Use Taylor Series for the square root:

$$\sqrt{Ax^2 + Bx + C} = \sqrt{C\left(\frac{A}{C}x^2 + \frac{B}{C}x + 1\right)} = \sqrt{C}\sqrt{1 + Y}$$

Where

$$Y = \frac{A}{C}x^2 + \frac{B}{C}x$$

Now the square root expansions gives

$$\sqrt{1 + Y} = 1 + \frac{Y}{2} - \frac{Y^2}{8} + \frac{Y^3}{16} + \ldots$$

And you would integrate

$$\int_0^h\sinh\left(\sqrt{C}\cdot\left(1 + \frac{Y}{2} - \frac{Y^2}{8} + \frac{Y^3}{16} + \ldots\right)\right)\ \text{d}x = D$$

Then you may try at first order, second order, third order and so on.

FIRST ORDER

$$\int_0^h\sinh\left(\sqrt{c}\cdot\left(1\right)\right)\ \text{d}x = D = h\cdot \sinh\sqrt{C}$$

And so on..

Comment: Special function recall: **Error Function** (Google it).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the your detailed solution. I tried the Tylor series expansion. But as it turned out, for higher orders, it gets difficult to solve the polynomial equation for $t$. I am ckecking purturbation methods to see if i can apply that up here. Any suggestions regarding that will be appreciated. Thanks!